# Char multiplication in C

Tags: c, char, multiplication

I have a code like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  char a=20,b=30;
  char c=a*b;
  printf("%c\n",c);
  return 0;
}
```

The output of this program is **X** .

How is this output possible if a*b=600 which overflows as char values lies between -128 and 127 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whether `char` is signed or unsigned is implementation defined. Either way, it is an integer type.

Anyway, the multiplication is done as `int` due to [integer promotions](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.1p1) and the result is converted to `char`.

If the value does not fit into the "smaller" type, it is implementation defined for a `signed char` how this is done. Far by most (if not all) implementations simply cut off the upper bits.

For an `unsigned char`, the standard actually requires (briefly) cutting of the upper bits.

So:

```
(int)20 * (int)20 -> (int)600 -> (char)(600 % 256) -> 88 == 'X'
```

(Assuming 8 bit `char`).

See the link and its surrounding paragraphs for more details.

Note: If you enable compiler warnings (as always recommended), you should get a truncation warning for the assignment. This can be avoided by an explicit cast (only if you are **really** sure about all implications). The gcc option is `-Wconversion`.

Comment: +1 Never knew "*the multiplication is done as `int` due to integer promotions and the result is converted to `char`*". I thought that the code will invoke undefined behavior if `char` is `signed` because of overflow.

Comment: @CoolGuy: I had to look into the standard myself for the conversion. But in general, all "smaller" integers are first promoted to `int` or `unsigned` (the latter only if `unsigned char` has the same width as `unsigned int`, similar for `short`, which is much more important). The effect is basically the same for most implementations, but a properly configured compiler (e.g. gcc: `-Wconversions`) should warn about truncation.

Comment: @CoolGuy: "undefined behavior" means it can do what it likes, including (but not limited to) just ignoring the upper bits that don't fit in the `char` (which is what most implementations do).

Comment: @IanAbbott: I think it was not the surprise what UB means, but that a lossy conversion actually is **not** UB, So, the standard behaves different for `char` "overflow" (semantical overflow, but technically conversion/truncation) and `int` (true) overflow. One of the nastynesses of type coercion.

Answer (score 3):

First off, the behavior is implementation-defined here. A `char` may be either `unsigned char` or `signed char`, so it may be able to hold `0` to `255` or `-128` to `127`, assuming `CHAR_BIT == 8`.

`600` in decimal is `0x258`. What happens is the least significant eight bits are stored, the value is `0x58` a.k.a. `X` in ASCII.

Comment: Detail: No overflow occurred.  `a`, `b` are converted to `int` before multiplication and `600` is in `int` range.

Comment: @chux Well, `0x258` doesn't fit in a generic `char` but I guess that's not called an overflow... will edit that.

Comment: @cad: That is a truncation. Typically for most (all?) implementations, but not defined by the standard for signed integers.

Answer (score 1):

<del>This code will cause undefined behavior if `char` is signed.</del>

I thought overflow of signed integer is undefined behavior, but conversion to smaller type is implementation-defined.

quote from [N1256](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) 6.3.1.3 Signed and unsigned integers:

> 3 Otherwise, the new type is signed and the value cannot be represented in it; either the
>   result is implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised.

If the value is simply truncated to 8 bits, `(20 * 30) & 0xff == 0x58` and 0x58 is ASCII code for `X`. So, if your system do this and use ASCII code, the output will be X.

Comment: You are right about overflow, but not conversion (had to look up myself to be sure:-) Btw: you should update your reference. That is not the current standard.

Answer (score -1):

First, looks like you have `unsigned char` with a range from 0 to 255.
You're right about the overflow.

```
600 - 256 - 256 = 88
```

This is just an ASCII code of 'X'.

Comment: No overflow occurred.  An implementation-defined conversion of 600 to a `char` did occur.

Comment: Well, that actually depends on the architecture.

Comment: It does not depend on architecture if overflow occurred here.  `a` and `b` are first promoted to `int` or `unsigned` (implementation dependent).  The product of 600 is made (no dependency on  architecture) and no overflow as this answer asserts.  The conversion of 600 to `char` is implementation defined.

Comment: I can be mistaken but I'm not sure they're promoted to int if e.g. 8-bit MCU is used.

Comment: they must always promoted to int, otherwise the compiler is not standard compliant. In actual situations you don't need to promote to int to get a wider result, as most architectures has widening multiplication, so you need a single 8x8->16 mul instruction